# 404 error in url rewriting to get user-friendly urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a static html website on a shared hosting.
I would like to turn these html files to user-friendly urls.
IE: `website.com/web-design.html` becomes `website.com/web-design/`
I am using these rules so that the corresponding html file is served when I request `website.com/web-design/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html
```

It works if I type in the browser `website.com/web-design` (without trailing slash), but instead with `website.com/web-design/` I get a 404 error:

```
The requested URL /web-design.html/ was not found on this server.
```

I want both urls (with and without trailing slash) to work...
It seems that a slash is added at the end of the html file, giving a 404.
I can't figure out how to fix it...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try your rule like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: With these rules it throws: `The requested URL /web-design/.html was not found on this server.`

Comment: Try the updated rules and What service provider do you have?

Comment: It's really strange: I deleted the .htaccess and nonetheless `website.com/web-design` is still mapped to `website.com/web-design.html`. It should have given a 404 error instead. I can't understand... It's an Italian company: Aruba

Comment: Try and clear your browser cache or try in a another browser